# Python imports not working after I switched to a new pc

Tags: python, import

I moved my work in progress project to my new pc (I was on windows 10, now i'm on windows 11), but after that, all the imports in it stopped working. I tried writing the file from 0, using a virtual environment, but nothing worked and I can't even import sys.
I get a "No module named 'sys'" error. The folder structure looks like this:

```
Projects
   Virtualenv
      main.py
      Libs
         site-packages
            cv2
            pygame
            ...
```

My python installation is in C:/Users/(my user directory)/Programs/Python/...
However, I am using a virtual environment and it should be using a local copy of the python installation (its libraries are in the folder structure I included above).
Anybody ever get this problem?

Comment: post the error messages you get. your question is useless without further information

Comment: What is the location of your python installation? Maybe installing in path like "C:\Program Files\PythonX.X" will cause errors of NTFS permission.